# Bypass firebase login in webApp

Tags: firebase, flutter

use case:
My flutter app(android, iOS and web) has phone authentication. On the mobile platforms(have phone auth) I generate a qr code that provides a https link. The link is a page in the app. The link targets the web platform. So when the user scans the QR code... Their browser will open up and my aim is to take them to the page (read only) in the app. However I don't want to force the user authenticate. Is there a way I can take them to the page without authenticating?